# Проблема с распознаванием речи в аудиофайле [Python + Speech Recogniton]

Tags: python, распознавание-речи

Всем привет , пытался распознать текст в аудиофайлах , при помощи либы , которую я указал в тайтле . В общем вот пример кода -

```
sample_audio =speech_recog.AudioFile('E:/Datasets/my_audio.wav')
with sample_audio as audio_file:
  audio_content = recog.record(audio_file)
recog.recognize_google(audio_content)
```

Ошибку выдает на строке с with ,а именно , ошибка в форме файла . Я пробовал и flac и wav , это все поддерживается либой , но тем не менее - ошибка.ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format
Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`speech_recognition` использует `wave` из стандартной библиотеки питона для чтения WAV файлов. `wave` не умеет работать с WAV файлами с плавающей запятой - float, по этому нужно использовать WAV файлы которые сохранены в целочисленном формате - integer.

Comment: А можно как - то конвертировать в целочисленный формат , прямо из питона?

Comment: @Sakura В SciPy's есть функция scipy.io.wavfile.write которая создает целочисленный файл из массива целых чисел. Нужно будет разобраться как перевести ваш wav файл в массив и потом перегнать его в нужный формат.

Comment: спасибо , попробую